# Reboots without a reason and fan not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: reboot, fan, fancontrol

I recently joined the Ubuntu community by installing Ubuntu on my Windows notebook (as dual boot, Notebook: HP 255 G8 with Ryzen 5500u, 512gb nvme ssd, 8gb ram). But I had some reboots without a reason so I realized I haven't heard the fan spinning when using Ubuntu. So in order to troubleshoot this problem I focused on fixing this fan issue. On Windows the fan works perfectly fine but when I run this command in Ubuntu:

```
sudo pwmconfig
```

I get the output

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

and the fan also doesn't appear when running sensors :

```
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tctl:         +36.9°C  

BAT1-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          12.97 V  
curr1:            N/A  

amdgpu-pci-0400
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:      724.00 mV 
vddnb:       681.00 mV 
edge:         +35.0°C  
slowPPT:       0.00 W  

nvme-pci-0300
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +28.9°C  (low  =  -0.1°C, high = +83.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +29.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +34.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +37.0°C  (crit = +226.8°C)
temp2:        +20.0°C
```

I wasn't able to troubleshoot this problem my self so I am hoping the great Linux (Unix)- community could help me out :)
As you might have already noticed I am not a very experienced user, so I don't know whether other Information are necessary for solving this issue.
Thank you for your responses!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, and Ubuntu in general. Could you [edit] your post to include the brand and model of computer you're using? If there's any other hardware details that you could share, that would also be helpful. Sometimes there are machine that require a little bit of extra work when installing anything that isn't Windows 

Comment: If your fans are not working over heating can cause reboots.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I now have added some Hardware Details. Can I somehow log the temperatures? To me the reboots really seem to be random, they often happen even when I don't use a lot of hardware power.

Answer (score 0):

I now fixed the problem by updating my BIOS. My fan also works now!